# When must inline params for UserControls have single quotes to be well formed?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have been just using what it wants for years and have never questioned it, however, can someone tell me why I have to use single quote vs double quotes in order to be a well formed tag?

**Error Msg:**
"The server tag is not well formed."

What are the **rules for the single quote enforcement**(ie: within a template...etc)?

```
 //not well formed
 <uc1:blaControl ID="bla" runat="server" Prop1="<%# Eval("Data") %>" />
```

vs

```
 //well formed
 <uc1:blaControl ID="bla" runat="server" Prop1='<%# Eval("Data") %>' />
 <asp:Literal ID="ControlTitle" runat="server" Text="<%# Title %>" />
 <asp:Literal ID="ControlTitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Title %>' />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the markup in the first is not valid SGML. The `"` inside the attribute are confused with the surrounding quotes so it's not clear where the attribute begins an ends. To get around this you need to keep them different.

```
// valid and will compile
<uc1:blaControl ID="bla" runat="server" Prop1='<%# Eval("Data") %>' />
```

The reason you can't alternatively use the following syntax which would be valid SGML, is that the C# inside the outer quotes becomes invalid and won't compile (single quotes denote a char).

```
 // valid but won't compile
 <uc1:blaControl ID="bla" runat="server" Prop1="<%# Eval('Data') %>" />
```

Comment: Prop1="<%# Eval('Data') %>" doesn't work, introduces a different parse error, "Too many characters in character".

Comment: Oh of course, it's C# hence it's trying to treat the bit inside the single quotes as a char which is invalid. That's why the outer tags must be single, I'll revise.

Comment: I have been playing some, Test="<%# CharTest('c') %>" is valid. So the rule of thumb is the surrounding quotes can go either way depending on the inner requirements of the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Xml allows you to use either single or  double quotes for atributtes, by using a single quotes in the attribute declaration it means that then you can use  double quotes inside the attribute value when you do for instance: Eval("something")