# Conditional display of table rows in a listview itemtemplate

Tags: asp.net, listview

I seen similar questions asked various places, but haven't really found an answer to this that works for me yet. Basically, I have a ListView where I want to hide table rows if a particular value in the data binding if a particular condition is true (most often if the value of the item is null or empty string). I've tried making the tr runat="server" and setting the condition on the visible property, but this returns a runtime error "The server tag is not well formed." Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="FullInfoListView">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="tablestripe" width="100%">
            <asp:Placeholder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr valign="top" class="eventrow1">
            <td colspan="2">
                <h3><%# Eval("FirstName") Eval("LastName") %></h3>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top" runat="server" Visible="<%# (bool)Eval("PhotoVis") %>">
            <td colspan="2">
                <img src="~/Userphoto/thumb/<%# Eval("NetworkLogin") %>.jpg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to have single quotes around the `Visible` setter:

```
<tr valign="top" runat="server" Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("PhotoVis") %>'>
     <td colspan="2">
        <img src='~/Userphoto/thumb/<%# Eval("NetworkLogin") %>.jpg' />
     </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You were missing the closing `%>`

Comment: Duh. Thanks. I'll blame it on the fact that it's Wednesday :)

Comment: +1: This is the easiest solution. Just so you know, you'll need to do the same thing for the image tag - use single quotes around the `src` attribute.

Comment: No worries, I have been doing this a long time and managed to ask this "stupid" question: When must inline params for UserControls have single quotes to be well formed? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257098/when-must-inline-params-for-usercontrols-have-single-quotes-to-be-well-formed

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap the row in a `PlaceHolder`:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("PhotoVis") %>'>
    <tr valign="top">
        <td colspan="2">   
            <img src='~/Userphoto/thumb/<%# Eval("NetworkLogin") %>.jpg' />   
        </td>   
    </tr>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

**EDIT**: Included single quotes around image `src` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `style="display:none"` instead of using `Visible`.